# Which controls are bound to my dataset?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dataset

Given a DataSet instance, is there any way I can find out which controls are bound to it's tables?

I want to stop everything binding to the DataSet, something like :

```
foreach (Control cont in dataset.ControlsBoundToMe)
{
    if (cont is DataGrid)
    {
        (cont as DataGrid).DataSource = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I assume you're talking about Winforms controls.

Then, on every form, you can access the [BindingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.bindingcontext.aspx) property, that would give you a binding manager from a particular datasource. Once you have this manager, you can access its binding collection and iterating over it.

Pseudo code:

```
var bindingManager = BindingContext[myDataSet.Tables[0]];
foreach (Binding binding in bindingManager.Bindings)
{
    var dataGrid = binding.Control as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid != null)
        dataGrid.DataSource = null;
}
```

Comment: I am using Winforms. Problem is I dont have access to the forms... This is occurring in the data access layer, so I only have the dataset in my class.

Comment: So I'm afraid you can't do that, unless you manually implement some sort of tracking system...

Comment: I had to implement the tracking system. Thanks.